# how to handle etcdserver: unhealthy cluster

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

When I add node in master of etcd cluster using this command:

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:2379/v3beta/members \
-XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"peerURLs": ["http://172.19.104.230:2380"]}'
```

It shows `{"error":"etcdserver: unhealthy cluster","code":14}`.

And I check the cluster status:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ~]# etcdctl member list
55a782166ce91d01, started, infra3, https://172.19.150.82:2380, https://172.19.150.82:2379
696a771758a889c4, started, infra1, https://172.19.104.231:2380, https://172.19.104.231:2379
```

It is fine. What should I do to make it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`etcd` source code](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/etcdserver/errors.go), it [returns](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/c55410ccea53bf613f10f6376ef870d3c81e2eec/etcdserver/server.go#L1474) `ErrUnhealthy` error code if [`longestConnected`](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/9c5426830b1b8728af14e069acfdc2a64dea768c/etcdserver/util.go#L65) method failed.

```golang
// longestConnected chooses the member with longest active-since-time.
// It returns false, if nothing is active.
func longestConnected(tp rafthttp.Transporter, membs []types.ID) (types.ID, bool) {
    var longest types.ID
    var oldest time.Time
    for _, id := range membs {
        tm := tp.ActiveSince(id)
        if tm.IsZero() { // inactive
            continue
        }

        if oldest.IsZero() { // first longest candidate
            oldest = tm
            longest = id
        }

        if tm.Before(oldest) {
            oldest = tm
            longest = id
        }
    }
    if uint64(longest) == 0 {
        return longest, false
    }
    return longest, true
}
```

So, `ectd` can't find appropriate member to connect.

Cluster's method [`VotingMemberIDs`](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/77e1c37787fb08d8faf29ecc4a3114f62e2fff68/etcdserver/api/membership/cluster.go#L824) returns list of *voting* members:

```
transferee, ok := longestConnected(s.r.transport, s.cluster.VotingMemberIDs())
if !ok {
    return ErrUnhealthy
}
```

```golang
// VotingMemberIDs returns the ID of voting members in cluster.
func (c *RaftCluster) VotingMemberIDs() []types.ID {
    c.Lock()
    defer c.Unlock()
    var ids []types.ID
    for _, m := range c.members {
        if !m.IsLearner {
            ids = append(ids, m.ID)
        }
    }
    sort.Sort(types.IDSlice(ids))
    return ids
}
```

As we can see from you report, there *are* members in your cluster.

> ```sh
> $ etcdctl member list
> > 55a782166ce91d01, started, infra3, https://172.19.150.82:2380, https://172.19.150.82:2379
> > 696a771758a889c4, started, infra1, https://172.19.104.231:2380, https://172.19.104.231:2379
> ```

So we should check members - are they voiting members, not [`learners`](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/10537), see [etcd docs | Learner](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3.12/learning/learner/)

[image: Raft learner]

```golang
// RaftAttributes represents the raft related attributes of an etcd member.
type RaftAttributes struct {
    // PeerURLs is the list of peers in the raft cluster.
    // TODO(philips): ensure these are URLs
    PeerURLs []string `json:"peerURLs"`
    // IsLearner indicates if the member is raft learner.
    IsLearner bool `json:"isLearner,omitempty"`
}
```

So, try to increase members count to provide a [quorum](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4.0/learning/design-learner/)
[image: etcd quorum]

To force creating members [try this](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/7171#issuecomment-404736553) `ETCD_FORCE_NEW_CLUSTER=“true"`

## Quorum

See also this post: [Understanding cluster and pool quorum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/understand-quorum)